# URL regex validation

Tags: javascript, regex

i made that:

```
 /^(http[s]?://){0,1}(www.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\.]{0,1}
```

and checked it with a validator but on my page it is not working:

```
var re = /^(http[s]?://){0,1}(www.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\.]{0,1};
if (!re.test(url)) { 
    alert("url error");
    return false;
}
```

i get this error

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Tue, 30 Nov 2010 14:23:10 UTC


Message: Expected ')' in regular expression
Line: 781
Char: 23
Code: 0
URI: http://*************************
```

Comment: What validator did you use? Was it JS-specific? Keep in mind that regexes are different by environment.

Comment: i have used js one... i don't know what was wrong

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have to escape your special characters (`/` and that `.` after `www` in this case) and att the missing trailing `/`, like this:

```
var re = /^(http[s]?:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\.]{0,1}/;
if (!re.test(url)) { 
    alert("url error");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what wrong with `http://localhost:8000/memcache?message=Cache+flushed%2C+all+keys+dropped.` ?

Comment: cause, the function is only for domains and IPs without PORT.

Answer (score 2):

I will post, although the question has been accepted.

That regex is still incomplete.

`http://www.-1-.de` is not a valid domain name but would pass your test.

Here's what I use:

```
~^
(?:ht|f)tps?://

(?:[a-z0-9] (?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?      \.)*

(?:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,62}[a-z0-9])
(?:\.[a-z]{2,5}){1,2}

$~ix
```

Covers http(s), ftp(s) and .co.uk TLDs and the like. Also covers subdomains which can be 1 character in length (`m.example.com` for mobile versions of webpages) but will not allow `m-.example.com`.

Surely some might object as to the regex's completeness, since `.pro` TLDs require at least 4 characters as a domain name. ;-)

Also IDN domain names will only pass my regex after conversion (i.e. in the "xn--" format).

Comment: how would i use it?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to know if the url really exists:

```
function url_exist($url){//se passar a URL existe
    $c=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);//get the header
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_NOBODY,1);//and *only* get the header
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);//get the response as a string from curl_exec(), rather than echoing it
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,1);//don't use a cached version of the url
    if(!curl_exec($c)){
        //echo $url.' inexists';
        return false;
    }else{
        //echo $url.' exists';
        return true;
    }
    //$httpcode=curl_getinfo($c,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    //return ($httpcode<400);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said Nick you have to escape `\` and `.` unless you're using another delimitor so your regex will become :

```
var re = '~(https?)://)?(www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}\.?~';
```

But be aware that your regex will match url like:

```
http://....aa.
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long research I build this reg expression. I hope it will help others too.......

```
   url = 'https://google.co.in';
   var re = /[a-z0-9-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\/?([^\s<>\#%"\,\{\}\\|\\\^\[\]`]+)?$/;
  if (!re.test(url)) { 
     alert("url error");
   return false;
 }else{
 alert('success')
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var regForUrl = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;

if (!regForUrl.test(url)) {
    alert('Invalid URL-- missing "http://" or "https://"');
}
```

Comment: Some explanation might be helpful here.