# Show validation message without using required

Tags: html, validation

I want to display a validation message only when a user types something in the input field. I can't put required in the input box.

```
<input type="url" class="form-control" name="website_url">
```

The input data should be a valid website URL.

Can I do this **without using Jquery or Javascript**?

Comment: you can achieve it through java script before posting form to the server.

Comment: ya u can, please check  [this](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

Comment: I found the pattern in HTML5 for validating the length for the textarea. so I was looking something similar in the HTML.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by javascript like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Enter your url: <input type="text" id="url" onfocusout="myFunction()">



<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("url");
    var re = //use valid regex here;
if (!re.test(url)) { 
    alert("url error");
    return false;
}

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

you have to  use valid regex for url like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314741/url-regex-validation)

but I prefer to do server side validation to in case javascript is off.

Comment: provide exact regex needed instead of forwarding to another link!

Comment: I have provide a link to follow.

Comment: append the regex instead of forwarding to another link and update your answer with snippet. so that people can understand easily.

Comment: I appreciate you for the answer. but I'm looking for a single line solution. I don't want to use Javascript or Jquery.

Comment: then you can specify type="url" like this https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: Seems like this force users to enter the full url https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_url (tried it with google.com, www.google.com, http://www.google.com, only the last one works)